# using rs2xml to display a database table with images

Tags: mysql, sql, jtable, blob

i my code i am trying to display contents of a database using left Join, which i have already done. i used rs2xml to display the left joined database table on a Jtable.

but the problem is that the db table has images on one of its columns. I stored those images as BLOBS. on trying to display my left joined db table, i get every other thing right except that instead of having the images a have some sets of codes in their place. my code looks like this...

```
private void retrvStaffList() {
    try {
        //this sql uses LEFT JOIN to merge tables with corresponding foreign keys
        //hence we it is going to display all staff with their specified info retrieved from all the tables in ONE table...
        String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT s.StaffName, d.DeptName, b.age, b.telephone,b.email, b.address, t.position, t.salary FROM Staffs AS s\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN  Departments as d ON d.DepartmentID = s.DepartmentID\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN BioData AS b ON b.BioID = s.StaffID\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN StatusTable AS t ON t.ownerID = s.StaffID";
        PreparedStatement pStmt2 = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pStmt2.executeQuery();
         do {
                //get the staff table...
                staffTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                staffTable.setEnabled(false);

            } while (rs.next());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StaffList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

i dont know if there is a way i can accomplish my task. i did some searches but the results i saw had to with people that stored paths to the images not the images themselves (as BLOBs). Please i really need a way out of this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I have no experience here, but is it possible that the format of the image in the blob is not what is expected? Can you look at the metadata to perhaps find a clue?

Comment: For example Google Chrome Browser stores Favicons in a blob in PNG format in a Sqlite database.

Comment: @Marichyasama...well...i can use the stored images for other uses like displaying it as a profile picture in my app without issues even irrespective of the file format. but the only issue here is making it show in Jtable as a picture...